# How to make a XGBoost DMatrix from a pandas dataframe with fields of type Sparse[uint8, 0]

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I have a pandas dataframe from which I want to create a train-test split to train an XGBoost model. The problem comes from the fact that my dataframe has a lot of fields of type  **Sparse[uint8, 0]**. This is necessary because I had to perform a one-hot encoding on some fields that would make the dataframe too large to store otherwise. This was done by running:

```
 df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['item_id', 'user_age', 'user_region'], sparse=True)
```

First I split my dataframe into the data/target and then generate my train/test split as follows

```
 dfX = df.drop('target', axis=1) 
 dfY = df[['target']] 
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dfX, dfY, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test are pandas dataframes but when I try to make xgb.DMatrix's:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)
```

I get the following error:

> DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
>                   Did not expect the data types in fields item_id_0, item_id_1, ... user_age_9.0, user_age_10.0, user_region_0.0, user_region_2.0 ...

So XGboost seems as if it doesn't know how to handle all my fields that were the result of the one-hot-encoding I performed earlier.

How do I solve this error? My intuition tells me that I should be representing my dataframes as csr matrices to then make DMatrix's from but I am not so sure

Comment: can you share the code you used for "one-hot-encoding" it seems like it is leaving some col with string values.